# HTML / JS - li extra data field

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently trying to create a hidden field in a current list (li) in which I can pass another field other than just the text value.

Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<ul id = "playlist" class="mejs-list" style="background: #00BFFF;list-style: none;  padding: 0;list-style-type: none;width: 300px; height: 300px;overflow: auto" >

<li data-leaves="47" class="current">Test</li>
<li data-leaves="47">Test2</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript (I simplified the code):

```
$(".mejs-list li").click(function() {
var audio_src = $(this).text();
alert(audio_src)
var test = $(this).dataset.leaves
alert(test )          
});
```

I get a display for "audio_src" no problem since this is simply the "text" of the item however I can not get the custom field to pass through.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't get it,what's the problem?

Comment: I can't get the custom property "leaves" to pass through.  The second alert isn't fired.

Comment: Please make a fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery objects have no `dataset` proprty. Don't "cast" `this` to a jQuery Object:

```
$(".mejs-list li").click(function () {
    var audio_src = $(this).text();
    alert(audio_src);
    var test = this.dataset.leaves;
    alert(test);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pq8nH/)

Also learn how to use `console.log` for [debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2011/05/26/console-log-say-goodbye-to-javascript-alerts-for-debugging.aspx). You can get alot more info that way, you can log and inspect objects to the console.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use **$(this).attr("dataset-leaves")** instead of **$(this).dataset.leaves**.

BTW, it is best practise to end each statement with a semi-comma.

Correction: should be **$(this).attr("data-leaves")**

Comment: I tried this just now. alert($(this).attr("dataset-leaves")) but it displays as "undefined",

Comment: My fault, it should be $(this).attr("data-leaves").

Comment: Your later comment also works. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) to return the value of `data-leaves`.

```
$('.mejs-list li').click(function() {

    var audio_src = $(this).text(),
        test = $(this).data('leaves');

    alert('audio source: '+ audio_src + '\n data-laves: '+ test);

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pWuh9/